# Is it possible to allow a user to log into a PostgreSQL database hosted on AWS without the key file?

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm looking to create a method which will allow a user to remotely log into Postgres hosted on an AWS instance without needing to give them the public key to the instance. Currently, I'm using SSH tunneling in Python to allow access.

```
try:
    with SSHTunnelForwarder(
         (IP_ADDRESS, 22),
         ssh_private_key=PATH_TO_KEY_FILE,
         ssh_username=USERNAME,
         remote_bind_address=('localhost', 5432)) as server:
            conn_str = "dbname=DB_NAME host='127.0.0.1' user=DB_USER password=DB_PASS port=%d" % server.local_bind_port
            conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_str)
            df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM %s ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT %d' % (table, num_rows), conn)
            conn.close()

    return df

except:
    print("Connection Failed")
```

Is there a way we can get around having to specify the key file?